# Polarization sum rule for Rarita-Schwinger field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, spinors

There are Rarita-Schwinger equations:
$$
\tag 1 (p\!\!\!/ - m)\psi_{\mu} = 0, \quad \gamma_{\mu}\psi^{\mu} = 0, \quad i\partial_{\mu}\psi^{\mu} = 0.
$$
So the polarization sum $D_{\mu \nu}(p) = \sum_{s}u^{s}_{\mu}\bar{u}^{s}_{\nu}$ (spinor wave for particle) must satisfy all of this relations. Also I've added the requirement of Hermiticity in a sense that $D_{\mu \nu}^{\dagger} = \gamma_{0}D_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{0}$ (Lagrangian of RS field, which is equal to the inverse propagator (while propagator contains polarization sum), must be constructed as $L = \bar{\psi}^{\mu}M_{\mu \nu}\psi^{\nu}$ and be real, so $M_{\mu \nu}^{\dagger} = \gamma_{0}M_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{0}$). As a result I get
$$
\tag 2 D_{\mu \nu}(p) = A(p\!\!\!/ + \sqrt{p^{2}})\left(g_{\mu \nu} - \frac{p_{\mu} p_{\nu}}{p^{2}} + \frac{i}{2\sqrt{p^{2}}}\varepsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}p^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma_{5}\right).
$$
By taking into account that $v^{s}_{\mu} = \gamma_{5}(-1)^{S + s}u^{-s}_{\mu}$ ($v^{s}$ is the spinor wave for antiparticle) I can get that 
$$
G_{\mu \nu} = \gamma_{5}D_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{5} = A(-p\!\!\!/ + \sqrt{p^{2}})\left(g_{\mu \nu} - \frac{p_{\mu} p_{\nu}}{p^{2}} - \frac{i}{2\sqrt{p^{2}}}\varepsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}p^{\alpha}\gamma^{\beta}\gamma_{5}\right),
$$
so 
$$
D_{\mu \nu}G^{\nu \alpha} = 0.
$$
But this result doesn't coincide with a "well-known" result. For example, [in article](http://www.nikhef.nl/pub/services/biblio/preprints/95-002A.pdf) ("Quantizing spin 3/2 fields" by M.D. Nykerk) there is a statement that (eq. 39)
$$
\tag 3 D_{\mu \nu} = A(p\!\!\!/ + m)\left( g_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{3}\gamma_{\mu}\gamma_{\nu} - \frac{2p_{\mu}p_{\nu}}{3p^{2}} - \frac{1}{3m}\left( \gamma_{\nu}p_{\mu} - \gamma_{\mu}p_{\nu}\right)\right).
$$
The authors have used (except $(1)$) the requirement that $D_{\mu \nu}D^{\nu \alpha} = D^{\ \alpha}_{\mu}$, which they together with $D_{\mu \nu}G^{\nu \alpha} = 0$ refer to as the properties of a projection operator, but anyway it *isn't* a projection operator, because
$$
G_{\mu \nu} + D_{\mu \nu} \neq g_{\mu \nu}.
$$
Also it isn't Hermitian in the sense of $D_{\mu \nu}^{\dagger} \neq \gamma_{0}D_{\mu \nu}\gamma_{0}$.

So, there is the question: Which sum is correct, $(2)$ or $(3)$? If only $(3)$, why? If both sums are correct, why there is a possibility of existence of (at least) two sums?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.